# How to get the transpose in sql (HANA)?

Tags: sql, pivot, hana

I have a query which returns the table which is like

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN type=1 THEN 'A' 
                 WHEN type=2 THEN 'B' 

           END) as TYPE,COUNT(*) AS COUNT
            from TYPE_TABLE GROUP BY TYPE
```

(I use case to have the count in each types).

```
count     type
_____     _____
123         A
124         B
120         C
```

I want to have the table to be like this

```
 A       B       C
___     ___     ___
123      124     120
```

So actually I need the transpose of the column count.How do I get this in HANA?

Comment: Are there only 3 types? Or is the count indefinite

Comment: What have you tried till now ? Check this link : https://blogs.sap.com/2014/01/02/table-transpose-in-sap-hana-modeling/

Comment: @Luv I looked into the following but instead of Modelling I would like to have a pure SQL solution

Comment: @Bennjoe Mordeno Only three types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure SQL solution (**SQL Server**)

```
select 
  [A] 
  , [B]
  , [C]
from
(
  select Type,[Count]
  from ( SELECT (CASE WHEN type=1 THEN 'A' 
             WHEN type=2 THEN 'B' 
             .....   
       END) as TYPE,COUNT(*) AS COUNT
        from TYPE_TABLE GROUP BY TYPE) Table1
) x
pivot
(
  SUM(Count)
  for Type in([A], [B], [C])
)p
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NOYF75200)

Comment: His COUNT is actually a result of COUNT(*) and not a column with the name count

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only **3**

you could just

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but u can certainly create 3 restricted measures in a calculation view on column "count" and filter for types - A,B,C.

TA-DA, rows would be transformed to columns.