# SQL Compare Two tables with column value difference

Tags: sql, pivot, hana

I've 2 tables with exact same structure and I would like compare the column values and display in specific format. I'm new to SQL. I tried with Minus function but its not helping. Find below scenario

Table 1

```
Key Col1 Col2      
1   110  AAA  
2   120  BBB
```

Table 2

```
Key  Col1    Col2  
1    111     CCC  
2    120     DDD
```

I need output in below format

```
Key   Field   Table1    Table2 
1     Col1    110       111 
1     Col2    AAA       CCC  
2     Col2    BBB       DDD
```

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks,
Milind

Comment: which SQL engine are you using? MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: You will need to look into `Pivot` functions and expressions

Comment: I'm using HANA SQL

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything about HANA SQL; but I could help solution it in SQL Server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131323/how-to-get-the-transpose-in-sql-hana/43131601 for a pure sql solution

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131323/how-to-get-the-transpose-in-sql-hana/43131601

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the transpose in sql (HANA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131323/how-to-get-the-transpose-in-sql-hana)

Comment: @milindrane . . . This is a very interesting restructuring.  It is not quite a transpose problem.  Quite curious.

Answer (score 1):

This is an arcane structure for bringing the tables together.  I think this will work:

```
select t1.col1, 
       (case when t2.key is not null then 'col2' else 'col1' end) as field,
       (case when t2.key is not null then t1.col2
             when seqnum = 1 then t1.col1
             when seqnum = 2 then t1.col2
        end) as Table1,
       (case when t2.key is not null then t2.col2
             when seqnum = 1 then t2.col1
             when seqnum = 2 then t2.col2
        end) as Table2
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and t1.col1 = t2.col1 left join
     (select tt2.*, row_number() over (partition by tt2.key order by tt2.key) as seqnum
      from table2 tt2
     ) tt2
     on t1.key = tt2.key and t2.key is null;
```